# Parameterised test in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I have a program, containing 3 parameterized methods, that receives arguments from the command line. I would like to test them and I have written a test in JUnit, by right clicking on the original class and clicking new Junit test. In the test class, I have annotated the class, as `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`, and the parameterized methods, as `@Parameters` and the `testmain` method as `@test`.

In each method, I have created a reference for the original class and I have called the methods and passed the required parameters. Now the there is an Initialization error, that says there are no public static methods in the test class. Can someone advise me if this is the right way to carry out a test and if not, what is the right way to do it.

Just to make myself clear, I shall also give an example of what I have done so far (this is not the original code.)

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
Public class customertest(){

@Parameters
public testmethod1(String a, String b){
customer test = new customer();
test.method1(a, b);
}

@Parameters
public testmethod2(String c, String d){
customer test = new customer();
test.method2(c, d);
}

@parameters
public testmethod3(String e){
customer test = new customer();
test.method3(e);

}

@Test
public static void testmain(String [] args){
customertest tester = new customertest();
tester.testmethod1(args[0], args[1]);
tester.testmethod2(args[2], args[3]);
tester.testmethod3(args[4]);


}




}
```

Comment: customertest is class that has unit tests in it?

Comment: yes and customer is the class I am testing.

Comment: so then you should definitely create instance of the tested class, not of class that obtains tests

Comment: yes thats what I did I specified wrong in the code am very sorry.

Comment: I have edited now. Sorry for my blunder.

Comment: what does the error looks like?

Comment: It says Initialization error and the failure trace, says throws an Illegal Argument Exception saying Wrong no of Arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using @Parameters completely wrong (in fact what you have in not valid Java syntax as the methods `testmethodsx` do not have return values).

See the example at this [site](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).

There should be only one `@Parameters` method. It should be `static` and return a `Collection<Object[]>`. The number of elements in the array must be equal to the number of arguments in the test class' constructor.

In the example you will see that `FibonacciTest` has a constructor that takes 2 arguments. Each array returned by the `@Parameteres` method contains 2 elements. These elements are passed to the constructor and the tests should use the fields to make parameter-specific tests.

Comment: I have gone through this example and other examples too. But all of them, enter values for the test in the @Parameters method. I would like to enter values from the command line. Is that possible??

Comment: Although there are ways to do this, I don't think that it is appropriate for JUnit. You could do it via system variables but if you are doing this to drive tests, this is a bad design.

Comment: Could you tell me a good means of running tests with command line arguments, on Eclipse. I use Eclipse Juno. Sorry for asking too many questions. I am new to Java. Thanks.

Comment: You can use environment variables as in this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html. You can google how to set an En Var in Eclipse. I will not go any further since this is REALLY not a good way to do this. This should be done with a properties file.